# Increasing resistance, by heat?

Tags: electrical-resistance

I was wondering the magnitude of effect to a conductor's resistance when heated by a few degrees. Can this be controlled way of changing conductor's resistance, or fixing in a system?

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a nice article about this on [the Hyperphysics web site](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/restmp.html).

The change in resistance with temperature is known as the [temperature coefficient of resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature_coefficient#Temperature_coefficient_of_electrical_resistance). For simple conductors like metals the change in resistivity is linearly proportional to the change in temperature:

$$ \Delta \rho = \alpha \Delta T $$

where $\alpha$ is the temperature coefficient of resistance. This is because in conductors the resistivity is determined by the mean free path of the conduction electrons, and this is roughly inversely proportional to temperature over small temperature ranges.

For semiconductors the variation of resistivity with temperature is more complicated because increased temperature can promote electrons into the conduction band and reduce resistivity. In semiconductors it's not uncommon to get an exponential decrease in resistivity (i.e. exponential increase in conductivity) with temperature.

At very low temperatures the resistivity is dominated by impurity levels and lattice defects and it is roughly independant of temperature.

The phenomenon does indeed have practical uses. For example [thermistors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor) are used in electrical circuits to compensate for changes in temperature.

Comment: +1, I've always found it interesting (and worth remembering) that for the noble and other "good conductivity" metals, the temperature coefficient goes as ~ 1/T (with T in degrees K) (mostly for room temperatures and above.)

Answer (score 0):

While this is probably not dealing with the exact phenomenon you're interested in, you should be aware that extraordinarily sensitive light detectors can be made using superconductors. If a superconducting wire is made thin enough, absorption by a single photon can temporarily raise the local temperature of the wire enough so that it is no longer superconducting. The change in resistance can be detected easily. Since the heated section cools very quickly and becomes once more a superconductor, the result is a detector which operates both at very low powers and high bandwidth, which is ordinarily not a possible combination.

This transition is not the same as the usual resistance temperature coefficient you're thinking of, though.